# overall page views driven by a referrer to one page (shell)

Tags: grep, tcsh, uniq, openbsd, access-log

Having a log file in the standard `combined` `access_log` format of nginx or apache, how would you, in UNIX shell, calculate the number of visits or page views (i.e. total requests) from each visitor (i.e. IP-address) that a given referrer once brought?

In other words, the number of ALL requests by each visitor that have found a link to your site on another site.

Answer (score 0):

The best snippet I could come up with is the following:

```
fgrep http://t.co/ /var/www/logs/access.log | cut -d " " -f 1 | \
fgrep -f /dev/fd/0 /var/www/logs/access.log | cut -d " " -f 1 | sort | uniq -c
```

What does this do?

We first find unique IP-addresses of visits that have `http://t.co/` in the log entry.  (Notice that this will only count visits that came directly from the ref, but not those that stayed and browsed the site further.)

After having a list of IP-addresses that, at one point, were referred from a given URL, we pipe such list to another `fgrep` through `stdin` — `/dev/fd/0` (a very inefficient alternative would have been `xargs -n1 fgrep access.log -e` instead of `fgrep -f /dev/fd/0 access.log`) for finding all hits from such addresses.

After the second `fgrep`, we get the same set of IP-addresses that we had in the first step, but now they repeat according to the total number of requests -- now `sort`, `uniq -c`, done. :)